# Custom UITableViewCell - adjust UILabel vertical alignment dynamically

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have a custom table cell. It has two labels (`title` and `description`), one below the other.

What I have right now is, `title` label `top = topMargin`. And `description` label `top = title` label `bottom + 10`.

But in some cases, there will be no description. In such cases, I want the `title` label to be centered vertically inside the cell. Is this possible? What constraints do I have to set?

Comment: Are your labels single-line only, and the rows are fixed-height? Or are the labels multi-line, so the row heights need to be dynamic?

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: @skt you can used stackview for manage this type of condition

Comment: @DonMag the labels will always be single line and the rows are fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UIStackView` makes it easy to do what you want.

- Create a prototype cell
- add two labels
- embed them in a stack view
- set the stack view's properties to:

  - Axis: Vertical
  - Alignment: Fill
  - Distribution: Fill Equally
  - Spacing: 10
- constrain the stack view Top/Leading/Trailing/Bottom to `0` to the cell's content view's default margins (or set your own "padding")
- set your fixed row height - with default labels + 10-point spacing + top and bottom margins, you'll probably want at least `67`
- connect the labels to `IBOutlet`s

When you set the text of the labels in `cellForRowAt indexPath:`, set the description label's `.isHidden` property to `true` if it *has* a description, or to `false` if it *doesn't*.

The result (with background colors for clarity):

[image]

The result without background colors:

[image]